# name 'pip' is not defined

Tags: python, django, pip

Since Python 2.7.9 pip is included when python is installed.

I've added

```
;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\scripts
```

to PATH, as everyone suggested. I've did a clean Windows install yesterday, and now i can't get pip to work in my python console as i did normally before.
I wanted to install all pip packages using requirements.txt file that i have exported in my previous Windows installation.

Can someone please tell me what has changed in the meanwhile and what am I missing?

Comment: Are getting a `NameError: name 'pip' not defined` exception?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for referencing to another question, as you said there i've mixed up cmd with python interpreter.. can't believe i did that :(